# Impossible to use grok date match correctly

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I have this message

> 2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open()
>   "/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server:
>   api.magritte.arte.tv, request: "GET
>   /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "api.magritte.arte.tv", referrer:
>   "https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"

And I parse it this way

```
grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM2}/%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:tid}:( \*%{NUMBER:cid})? %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}(?:, client: (?<client>%{IP}|%{HOSTNAME}))(?:, server: %{IPORHOST:server})(?:, request: %{QS:request})?(?:, upstream: \"%{URI:upstream}\")?(?:, host: %{QS:host})?(?:, referrer: \"%{URI:referrer}\")?"}
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
```

When a new message arrives the following behaviour occurs

1. message sent to rabbit : OK
2. message read from rabbit : OK
3. problem when logstash read message

> "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid
>   format: \"2016/02/22 08:40:10\" is malformed at \"/02/22
>   08:40:10\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}

But I have no idea where my error is. using http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result all seems OK

[image: grok analysis]

The full log in the logstash is

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-02-22T08:43:29.968000+0100", :message=>"Failed action. ", :status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2016.02.22", :_type=>"nginx_error", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x75f8f9a0 @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x402f1514 @store={}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server: api.magritte.arte.tv, request: \"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\", host: \"api.magritte.arte.tv\", referrer: \"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos\"", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-02-22T07:40:10.000Z", "path"=>"/var/log/nginx/api.magritte.arte.tv_error.log", "host"=>["magritte.arte.tv", "\"api.magritte.arte.tv\""], "type"=>"nginx_error", "application"=>"api", "timestamp"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10", "severity"=>"error", "pid"=>2127, "tid"=>0, "cid"=>193, "errormessage"=>"open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory)", "client"=>"192.168.144.95", "server"=>"api.magritte.arte.tv", "request"=>"\"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\"", "referrer"=>"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x27ca0e3f @store={"message"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server: api.magritte.arte.tv, request: \"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\", host: \"api.magritte.arte.tv\", referrer: \"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos\"", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-02-22T07:40:10.000Z", "path"=>"/var/log/nginx/api.magritte.arte.tv_error.log", "host"=>["magritte.arte.tv", "\"api.magritte.arte.tv\""], "type"=>"nginx_error", "application"=>"api", "timestamp"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10", "severity"=>"error", "pid"=>2127, "tid"=>0, "cid"=>193, "errormessage"=>"open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory)", "client"=>"192.168.144.95", "server"=>"api.magritte.arte.tv", "request"=>"\"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\"", "referrer"=>"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"}, @lut={"type"=>[{"message"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server: api.magritte.arte.tv, request: \"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\", host: \"api.magritte.arte.tv\", referrer: \"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos\"", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-02-22T07:40:10.000Z", "path"=>"/var/log/nginx/api.magritte.arte.tv_error.log", "host"=>["magritte.arte.tv", "\"api.magritte.arte.tv\""], "type"=>"nginx_error", "application"=>"api", "timestamp"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10", "severity"=>"error", "pid"=>2127, "tid"=>0, "cid"=>193, "errormessage"=>"open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory)", "client"=>"192.168.144.95", "server"=>"api.magritte.arte.tv", "request"=>"\"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\"", "referrer"=>"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"}, "type"], "[type]"=>[{"message"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server: api.magritte.arte.tv, request: \"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\", host: \"api.magritte.arte.tv\", referrer: \"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos\"", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-02-22T07:40:10.000Z", "path"=>"/var/log/nginx/api.magritte.arte.tv_error.log", "host"=>["magritte.arte.tv", "\"api.magritte.arte.tv\""], "type"=>"nginx_error", "application"=>"api", "timestamp"=>"2016/02/22 08:40:10", "severity"=>"error", "pid"=>2127, "tid"=>0, "cid"=>193, "errormessage"=>"open() \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\" failed (2: No such file or directory)", "client"=>"192.168.144.95", "server"=>"api.magritte.arte.tv", "request"=>"\"GET /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg HTTP/1.1\"", "referrer"=>"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"}, "type"]}>>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2016.02.22", "_type"=>"nginx_error", "_id"=>"AVMH7uSoo1ZDC2Pzezhl", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2016/02/22 08:40:10\" is malformed at \"/02/22 08:40:10\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

I think it's a quote issue ...
1

> Message in nginx logfile 2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193
>   open()
>   "/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server:
>   api.magritte.arte.tv, request: "GET
>   /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "api.magritte.arte.tv", referrer:
>   "https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"
>   It's the one I use to do my grok parsing (logstash sourceside)

2. rabbitmq message payload

> {"message":"2016/02/22 08:40:10 [error] 2127#0: *193 open()
>   \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.144.95, server:
>   api.magritte.arte.tv, request: \"GET
>   /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1\", host: \"api.magritte.arte.tv\", referrer:
>   \"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos\"","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-02-22T07:40:10.000Z","path":"/var/log/nginx/api.magritte.arte.tv_error.log","host":["magritte.arte.tv","\"api.magritte.arte.tv\""],"type":"nginx_error","application":"api","timestamp":"2016/02/22
>   08:40:10","severity":"error","pid":2127,"tid":0,"cid":193,"errormessage":"open()
>   \"/etc/nginx/nginx/html/static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg\"
>   failed (2: No such file or
>   directory)","client":"192.168.144.95","server":"api.magritte.arte.tv","request":"\"GET
>   /static-cdn.arte.tv/resize-preprod/nQa5oWnNDknADSxe0mPEMd5McUA=/940x530/smart/default/prog_img/IMG_APIOS/051000/051700/051757-001_1137283_32_202.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1\"","referrer":"https://api.magritte.arte.tv/api/oauth/user/documentation/opa/endpoint/27/-api-opa-v2-videos"}
>   Some backslashes are added

3. This backslash prevent logstash (target side) to correctly handle the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this, it works :)

```
 grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM2}/%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:p_id}#%{NUMBER:t_id}:( \*%{NUMBER:c_id})? %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}(?:, client: (?<client>%{IP}|%{HOSTNAME}))(?:, server: %{IPORHOST:server})(?:, request: %{QS:request})?(?:, upstream: %{QS:upstream})?(?:, host: %{QS:vhost})?(?:, referrer: \"%{URI:referrer}\")?"}
    }
  date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

Comment: if all you need is the timestamp, then `"(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM2}/%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND})"` is all you need. :)   thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A grok pattern is available, that can solve your problem.

```
grok {
       match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}" ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve my issue, in the log I have ``` "@timestamp" => "0016-02-22T10:52:49.000Z",``` I don't get why I have 0016 instead of 2016

Comment: In fact, the problem is that the date start with the year but not for %DATESTAMP so it works with `match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM2}/%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:p_id}#%{NUMBER:t_id}:( \*%{NUMBER:c_id})? %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}(?:, client: (?<client>%{IP}|%{HOSTNAME}))(?:, server: %{IPORHOST:server})(?:, request: %{QS:request})?(?:, upstream: \"%{URI:upstream}\")?(?:, host: %{QS:vhost})?(?:, referrer: \"%{URI:referrer}\")?"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `y` instead of `Y` in `date` filter.

[joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```